# Why do JSF properties files not accept non-ASCII characters in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, utf-8, properties-file

I wonder, why do JSF properties files not accept non-ASCII characters in Eclipse?

I have some properties file named "messages.properties", I've to write in unicode escapped characters for non-ASCII characters, example:

```
title=\u01af\u0020\u0a3f0
header=\u0ff0\u0020\u0ab1
```

This means that customers cannot edit these properties files using regular text editors.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3):

This stems in the fact that [`java.util.Properties.load(InputStream)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) uses ISO-8859-1.

> The load(InputStream)  /  store(OutputStream, String)  methods work the same way as the load(Reader)/store(Writer, String) pair, except the input/output stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding. Characters that cannot be directly represented in this encoding can be written using Unicode escapes  ; only a single 'u' character is allowed in an escape sequence. The native2ascii tool can be used to convert property files to and from other character encodings.

It has been a problem for ages. I've solved it with struts by implementing custom tags that make encoding transformations, but it is generally a pain.

Java 6 introduces the `Properties.load(Writer)`, which works fine with UTF-8, but it seems it isn't widely adopted yet.

I'd suggest using [AnyEdit tools](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) to convert to and from the unicode notation.

As for the end-users - if they are to edit properties files (which sounds strange), then you can let them write in whatever characters they like and later convert the files using native2acii (or a wrapper of it)

Comment: Thanks any way, I have write simple program to convert to unicoded format text, but I was asking because it will represent a very huge problem for end users!
Also, JBoss Tools contains a plugin that allow modification of properties file by writting directly native languages (such as Arabic, chines and so force, )

Comment: It is a very small web app, so the end-user is a non-technical deployer that gonna do some changes to properties/css files before deploying

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessary anymore since Eclipse 4.2 (Juno, 2012). Eclipse will take care of this transparently when you use the builtin properties file editor. It will present and accept the values in UTF-8, but it will under the covers silently convert to `\uXXXX` format. Noted should be that this has some strange side effects in combination with Git plugin (e.g. old lines deleted during merge), it works best if you close all properties files before pulling/pushing.

If you're not on Eclipse 4.x yet, consider using `native2ascii` tool found in `/bin` folder of the JDK installation directory to convert UTF-8 properties files to ASCII properties files, as described in [javadoc of `java.util.Properties` class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

You can keep the "original" properties files (give them for example an `.utf8` extension) and use a batch/shell file to convert them like this:

```
cd c:\path\to\properties\files
c:\path\to\jdk\bin\native2ascii.exe -encoding UTF-8 text_cs.properties.utf8 text_cs.properties
c:\path\to\jdk\bin\native2ascii.exe -encoding UTF-8 text_ja.properties.utf8 text_ja.properties
c:\path\to\jdk\bin\native2ascii.exe -encoding UTF-8 text_zh.properties.utf8 text_zh.properties
# You can add more properties files here.
```

This way you can just edit the `.utf8` files and run the batch/shell script once to do the conversion of native characters to `\uXXXX`. Also see [this blog entry](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JavaPropertiesFiles).

#### See also:

- [How to use UTF-8 in resource properties with ResourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle/)

Comment: @BalusC, can you please provide a clarification. I read some of your examples on this question. What if the original properties file is not in utf-8 but in iso 8859-1 encoding (as it should per the spec). This file contains special characters like 'é' which belongs to iso 8859-1 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout). Why i am still getting mojibake whey trying to display it (in a web page).

Answer (score -2):

just save the .properties file as UTF-8 format and it works for me.

Comment: I open the .properties from notepad and save as UTF-8 then edit it from Eclipse, then it pops out a warning, choose UTF-8, and it can pass compile.